# Does anyone know how to keep LESS CSS from getting scrambled by jquery plugins?

Tags: jquery, css, less, superfish

I am trying to use [Semantic Grid System](http://semantic.gs/) -- which uses [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage) --and additionally I am using [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) and the [JQuery Corner](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) plugin.

My problem is that when I [apply](http://so.toypizza.com/sffixed.html) superfish, it scrambles some LESS-generated styles that work perfectly [before](http://so.toypizza.com/fixed.html).  The delta between the two pre-ceding examples is the addition of the the "superfish.css", not applying the superfish() call in jquery.

(for the record, I know that some have reported difficulty with using "corner" and "superfish" before; I have successfully used them together with JQuery 1.7 and 1.7.1 so long as you call corner after fish and apply corner to a div wrapped outside of the fish ul)

Obviously I am at the initial steps of building a Semantic Grid layout that I will use as the base for my projects...and to find that Semantic / LESS seems to choke so quickly on a menu is SO disappointing that I cannot believe that the error is not mine.

Any solution or best practice to avoid this issue as I move forward would be appreciated.

Comment: If you take a look at this example, you see that I am getting some the parent slements of the superfish menu to be visible now:  http://so.toypizza.com/sffixed.html  I think that the solution is to not let any jquery run before less css has finished processing so that superfish gets "actual" dimensions of parent rendering.   does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can SGS be run without less.js, thus having you compile the stylesheet compiled beforehand?
I would recommend going this way.